# Does Thrown Exception Prevent Queueable Jobs From Executing?

Tags: apex, exception, queue

I'm running into this strange issue regarding the Queueable Apex and Exception handling.

I have something like this:
I'm querying for an Email Template(Only one)

```
List<EmailTemplate> emailTemplate = [Select Id, Subject, HtmlValue, Body from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName =: eTemplate];
```

Then

```
if(emailTemplate != null && !emailTemplate.isEmpty()){
    //My logic here
}
else

{
    //Kicking a queuable here to set the field(to TRUE) that fires this functionality
    throw new MyException('something bad happened!');
}
```

Now the logic in the else block doesn't fire the queuable jobs.I think the "**THROW**" statement doesn't let the queuable to fire.

Is there any logic that might help here

Comment: emailTemplate will never be null.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an uncaught exception will cause the entire transaction to roll back, including any executed jobs, DML Operations, etc. You would have to remove your `throw` if you want the job to fire.

If you want to surface an error in *Visualforce*, you can just use `ApexPages.addMessage` or `ApexPages.addMessages`, depending on what you're most comfortable with. As mentioned in the comments, your code structure may need to change to properly handle the case where your query fails to find a record.

While it's not the only paradigm that works, I find it better to avoid exceptions in your execution path where possible. The common approach is to query to a list and check if it is empty.

```
List<EmailTemplate> candidates = [/*query*/];
if (candidates.isEmpty())
{
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPage.Message(
        ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'No template found'
    ));
}
else
{
    // execute job
}
```

Comment: Yeah ..it worked fine without the throw exception....the reason I'm using the throw statement is to show the exception on our UI(VF with ExtJs) which is a combination of almost 10 objects.I'm trying to figure out if there is any alternate way